# How to display user information after successful login in Java with Jframe[login form]

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, jframe

So i got all of my connection to database code and comparing user provided login info with database now i need to somehow get all of users info and display it in jframe.

And any other advise on how I should do this kind of login form faster or better is welcome.

```
try{ Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection

    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/newbase","root","12345");

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT UserName , Password FROM newbase.namudarbaireg;");
    rs.next();  
    do {   
    name1 = rs.getString("UserName");
    pass1 = rs.getString("Password");
    if ((name1.equals(name)) && (pass1.equals(pass)))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                //so i want here after successful login not to write success
                 //but to show all user information
            }
    else  {

    }
    rs.next();
    } 
    while (!(name1.equals(name)) && (pass1.equals(pass)));
  }
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just pass the data you've got in here into a JFrame, so instead of having just `SELECT UserName , Password` use `SELECT *` and pass it to JFrame like this:

```
Frame f = new Frame (str); //Use this to open the JFrame
f.setVisible(true);

class Frame extends JFrame {

    private String str;

    public Frame (String str) {
        this.str = str;
        this.add(new JLabel(str, JLabel.CENTER));
    }

    public String getString() {
        return this.str;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but its sad that Im really new to coding so I dont really understand the code you wrote and how is this going to display user info when i launch jframe :(

Comment: Well you would pass your String parameter (your user info) into the JFrame, and then it would display it in a label

Comment: I i think i didint explain everything in my question correctly because there is other user info also in data base like his number , email and something else so i need to display all items in that row where user is at.

Comment: Well you can just store those in a String array and pass that into the JFrame instead